# I cannot print a variable to a file

Tags: perl

I am attempting to print a variable out to an file (HTML) and nothing I try seems to work.

I have verified that the variable does indeed contain data by printing it to STDOUT, however it never gets printed to the file.

Here is the code:

```
#BEGIN Replication Table
$REPstatCmd = "/bin/rstat";
@REPstat = split /\n/,`$REPstatCmd`;
@REPstatG0 = split / /, $REPstat[1];
$REPstatG0C1 = $REPstatG0[0];


print OUTPUT "<td valign=top><table><tbody><tr><th class=title>Replication Stats</th></tr><tr><td>\n";
print OUTPUT $REPstatG0C1;
print OUTPUT "</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></h2>\n";
```

The output of rstat looks like this:

```
Group          Remote Server      Local Done    Remote Done    Difference
0         drhost01_72                0              0
1         drhost01_72            7,582          7,582
2         drhost01_72      102,108,940    102,108,905            35
3         drhost01_72        5,584,312      5,584,312
4         drhost01_72       86,466,240     86,466,210            30
5         drhost01_72       22,898,028     22,898,028
6         drhost01_72            2,366          2,366
7         drhost01_72       53,106,257     53,106,236            21
8         drhost01_72    1,003,226,281  1,003,225,641           640
```

If I do this:

```
print $REPstatG0C1;
```

I get the following as expected:

```
0
```

The Output File looks like this:

```
</table></td><td valign=top><table><tbody><tr><th class=title>Replication Stats</th>
</tr><tr><td>
</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></h2>
```

The REPstatG0C1 variable is clearly skipped, it should be at line 2.

My File Handler looks like this if it is relevant:

```
open OUTPUT, ">index.html";
```

Any ideas??

Comment: I ran the same script and it worked just fine for me; what version of Perl are you on?

Comment: Not that that should make any difference. Are you able to include your whole script? You've clearly removed *some* stuff and I'm wondering if there's a transcription error in what you've provided that corrects the *actual* fault.

Comment: Have you tried your script with the `use strict` pragma? You should probably add `use warnings` as well.

Comment: I thought the same thing, perhaps another section is throwing it off, however I can print other variables out w/o issue.

I'm reluctant to paste the whole code due to company policies and its length..

Anything in particular I should look into?

I just tried this section in a standalone script and it did indeed work...

Comment: the version of perl is 5.8.8 on AIX 6.1

Comment: Try `print OUTPUT qq{'$REPstatG0C1'} or die "failed: $!"`. It will die if the print statement fails and it will surround your output by single quotes.

Comment: I changed the line to `print OUTPUT qq{'$REPstatG0C1'} or die "failed: $!";` and the file output now looks like:

`</table></td><td valign=top><table><tbody><tr><th class=title>Replication Stats</th></tr><tr><td>
''</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></h2>`

Comment: You could say `chomp(@REPstat=qx[$REPstatCmd])` instead of `@REPstat=split /\n/,qx[$REPstatCmd];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$REPstatG0C1` contains the string `0`, then it also contains a trailing carriage return. When the file is dumped to a terminal, the rest of the line overwrites the zero.

```
$ perl -e'print "0\rabc\n"'
abc
```

You can verify this by using `less`

```
0^Mabc
```

or `od -c`

```
$ perl -e'print "0\rabc\n"' | od -c
0000000   0  \r   a   b   c  \n
0000006
```

But I don't see how you'd get `"0\r"` from that code, so I believe something you said isn't true. Find out what, and you'll find your problem.

Comment: I thought of stray carriage returns as well, however I don't see where/how either.

I checked the output of the command rstat by doing this

   `rstat>rstat.out`

then read the rstat.out with VI, :SET LIST & only seen carriage returns at the ends of the lines as expected, which is what I'm splitting on earlier in the code.

    `@REPstat = split /\n/,`$REPstatCmd`;`

Comment: The only part I left out of the output I'm expecting is part of the string (b/c it contains the company name), but if it helps find the solution here is what I did.

-changed print OUTPUT $REPstatG0C1; to print $REPstatG0C1; then ran it like this:

`perl script.pl|od -c`

It returns this:

`0000000    S   E   F   C   U   0
0000006`

So I am not seeing a carriage return in that variable..

Comment: What's what the `od -c` of the file? (feel free to replace confidential letters with `x`) Let's get this clear: The problem is NOT with the `print`.

Comment: I piped the script to od -c and got the following. OutputLine1:`0000000 S E F C U 0`
OutputLine2:`0000006`

Comment: change this line @REPstat = split /\n/,`$REPstatCmd`;           @REPstat = qx($REPstatCmd); it is not required to add split

Comment: What's what the `od -c` *of the file*? (i.e. the case where it doesn't work)

Comment: od -c of the "OUTPUT" html file? If so the particular section of the html file is here:
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QRhwAYAc)

Comment: Again, I don't believe that. As long as you focus on that being the problem, you won't find the actual problem.

Comment: I agree, however I'm able to print to this file handler many times (hundreds) during the run of this script with no issues. The regular "print" to the console shows no issues with the contents of the variable, and looking at the output of the command directly using od -c shows no stray "special" characters. I've even tried `rstat >rstat.out` then reading that file into an array and I get the same results. I am really stumped.

Comment: Check what `print` returns. Maybe provide `use Devel::Peek; Dump($var);`. But better yet, provide code that replicates the problem.

Comment: `Dump($var)` returns this: `SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x202057f4
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = ()
`

Comment: Sorry, typo in the Dump command. Here is the output: `SV = PV(0x2020bac0) at 0x2020570c
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x20029888 "SEFCU0"\0
  CUR = 6
  LEN = 8`

Comment: Dump confirms it's a just plain ordinary string.

Comment: great! It further lends to the why wont it print mystery?

Comment: I believe the rstat program sends the output to both STDOUT & STDERR which was throwing this off. I changed the command to `$REPstatCmd = "/bin/rstat 2>/dev/null";` and now it is working.

the Devel::Peek tipped it off, I noticed that my string was displayed at the end like this`SV = PV(0x2020bac0) at 0x2020570c
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x20029888 "SEFCU0"\0
  CUR = 6
  LEN = 8
SEFCU0`